# minimum memory footprint for Linux and ROS melodic (cameras, lidar)

Tags: ros, linux, ros-melodic, footprint, memory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at "Jetson Nano " Quad Core ARM64 @1.47GHz with max 4GByte RAM and max 16GByte eMMC.

It comes with a Ubuntu install, so seems like a good match,

Is this memory footprint enough for an autonomus droid with cameras and Lidar ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319170/minimum-memory-footprint-for-linux-and-ros-melodic-(cameras,-lidar)/) by [Traversity](https://answers.ros.org/users/40568/traversity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-22**:\

> for an autonomus droid

may be me, but wow, we're creating droids now? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is plenty enough. You can run ROS with GUIs on a Raspberry Pi 3 (with 1 GByte of RAM) using the desktop environment with no problem.

With the desktop environment disabled on my Raspberry Pi 3 I have a 70 Mbyte RAM footprint.
If you are going to compile big projects (using multiple jobs with gcc/g++) make sure to create a swap file in case you fill the RAM!

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1